# Что такое _ в методах TryParse, TryGetValue

Tags: c#, .net

Я конечно мог упустить некоторые обновления языка из виду, но что за поле, или это вовсе даже не поле.

К примеру:

```
IPAddress.TryParse("someIP", out _); // ??
```

Куда денется результат выходного параметра `_`, т.к. если попробовать его использовать, то его просто нет.

Comment: Ассоциация: [C# Variable Name “_” (underscore) only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6308078/2553424).

Comment: _Куда денется результат выходного параметра `_`_ - никуда :-) в этом и смысл :)

Comment: Это очень странное и подозрительное поле/переменная...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Начиная с C# 7.0, имя `_` (подчёркивание), передаваемое в `out var`, стало обозначать [пустую переменную](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/discards) (discard operator). Она предназначена для сообщения компилятору о том, что мы не нуждаемся в возвращаемом значении, благодаря чему он может провести ряд оптимизаций *(например, удалить весь код, вычисляющий это значение, — прим. пер.)*.

  Пример:

  ```
  void Test(out int i) => i = 1;

  Test(out _); // Хоть переменная "_" нигде не объявлена, в C# 7.0 эта строка 
               // не вызовет ошибки компиляции

  var r = _;   // error CS0103: The name '_' does not exist in the current context
  ```
- Также он может быть полезен при деконструкции (ещё одно нововведение C# 7.0) в случае, если нам не нужны все значения кортежа.

  Пример:

  ```
  var Person = ("John", "Smith");

  var (First, _) = Person; // Переменная "_" снова не объявлена

  Debug.Print(First); // Выводит "John"
  Debug.Print(_); // error CS0103: The name '_' does not exist in the current context
  ```

Однако при наличии переменной `_` поведение компилятора на `out var _` [не определено](https://gist.github.com/MadsTorgersen/f6c61b60a81b872140e6f4d7ca7de377).

*P. S.: Как @maf-soft [указал в комментариях](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308078/c-sharp-variable-name-underscore-only#comment74656074_43796948)*, здесь нет никакой проблемы. При наличии в области видимости явно объявленной `_` компилятор трактует код как в старых версиях.

---

*Данный ответ является вольным переводом [ответа участника MotKohn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796948/2553424) на вопрос «[C# Variable Name “_” (underscore) only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6308078/2553424)».*